# In R, join data frames by group between start and end dates

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have two data frames:

1. `df1` contains three columns: start date (`date_start`), end date (`date_end`), and severity classification (`category`)
2. `df2` has one column of dates (`date`) that advance by one day for the month of January 2020

How can I join `df1` to `df2` such that the `category` in `df1` is filled between `date_start` and `date_end`?

Example Data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 2))
colnames(df1)[1:3] <- c('date_start','date_end','category')
df1$date_start <- c(as.Date('2020-01-02'),
                    as.Date('2020-01-10'))
df1$date_end <- c(as.Date('2020-01-05'),
                  as.Date('2020-01-13'))
df1$category <- c('moderate','strong')

df2 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 1, nrow = 15))
colnames(df2)[1] <- 'date'
df2$date <- seq.Date(as.Date('2020-01-01'),
                     as.Date('2020-01-15'),
                     1)

df1
df2
```

The ideal data frame would look like this:

```
         date category
1  2020-01-01       NA
2  2020-01-02 moderate
3  2020-01-03 moderate
4  2020-01-04 moderate
5  2020-01-05 moderate
6  2020-01-06       NA
7  2020-01-07       NA
8  2020-01-08       NA
9  2020-01-09       NA
10 2020-01-10   strong
11 2020-01-11   strong
12 2020-01-12   strong
13 2020-01-13   strong
14 2020-01-14       NA
15 2020-01-15       NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `join_by`:

```r
library(dplyr)
left_join(df2, df1, by = join_by(between(date, date_start, date_end))) %>% 
  select(date, category) %>% head(n = 15)

#          date category
# 1  2020-01-01     <NA>
# 2  2020-01-02 moderate
# 3  2020-01-03 moderate
# 4  2020-01-04 moderate
# 5  2020-01-05 moderate
# 6  2020-01-06     <NA>
# 7  2020-01-07     <NA>
# 8  2020-01-08     <NA>
# 9  2020-01-09     <NA>
# 10 2020-01-10   strong
# 11 2020-01-11   strong
# 12 2020-01-12   strong
# 13 2020-01-13   strong
# 14 2020-01-14     <NA>
# 15 2020-01-15     <NA>
```

Comment: I get an error that the function ```join_by``` could not be found. This is after loading ```library(dplyr)``` and also trying ```...dplyr::join_by(...```.

Comment: you have to update `dplyr`

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, use the `sqldf` package:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("SELECT df2.date, df1.category 
       FROM df2
       LEFT JOIN df1 
       ON df2.date BETWEEN df1.date_start AND df1.date_end")
```